# Como abrir uma tela com navigation drawer a partir de um botão?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Estou desenvolvendo meu TCC e não tenho muito conhecimento em Android ainda, porem seguindo alguns tutoriais consegui montar um app básico. Mas não estou conseguindo e nem tenho noção de como abrir uma tela com navigatiodrawer depois que clicar no botão "Login" e o cadastro estiver ok.

Creio que tenha que colocar na classe loginActivity, o código:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
            }
        });
        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que você está desfazendo minhas formatações?

Comment: desculpe, pc tá doido aqui

Comment: Preciso acrescentar coisas na minha pergunta!

Comment: Clique em EDITAR, e para formatar código, selecione ele todo e clique em `{}`

Comment: Obrigada pela informação!

Comment: Pelo Android Studio ele cria automaticamente uma `Navigation Drawer Activity` para vc, ai basta vc usar para customizar o `layout` do jeito que deseja.

Comment: Nem era isso, faltava uma intent kkkkk, msm assim mt obrigada!